# Ошибка TypeError в Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Я хочу написать программу с помощью pygame, которая рандомно отрисовывает чёрный и белые квадраты по сетке, но при запуске получаю ошибку

TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо

```
import pygame
from random import randint
pygame.init()

Size=40
FPS=60

White = (220, 220, 220)
Black = (0,0,0)
Yellow = (255,255,0)

Color=Yellow
#по рофлу

Wx,Wy=800,600
window = pygame.display.set_mode((Wx,Wy))

i=2
#тоже по рофлу

clock=pygame.time.Clock()

def Draw():
    Rx,Ry=0,0
    for Padla1 in range(0,Wy,Size):
        for Padla2 in range(0,Wx,Size):
            i=randint(0,1)
            if i==1:
                Color=White
            else:
                Color=Black
            pygame.draw.rect(window,White,(Rx,Ry),(Size,Size))
            Rx += Size
        Ry += Size
            

Running=True
while Running:
    for EVENT in pygame.event.get():
        if EVENT.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Running=False
        if EVENT.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if EVENT.key==pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                Running=False

    Draw()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: `pygame.draw.rect(..., (Rx, Ry, Size, Size))`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Кстати, там в pygame.draw.rect(window?White,((Rx, Ry, Size, Size)) вместо White должно быть Color